# How can I switch ON/OFF AIRPLANE mode and wifi using Appium?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, mobile, appium

How can I switch ON/OFF AIRPLANE mode and wifi using Appium ?

Selenium has below option:

```
NetworkConnection mobileDriver = (NetworkConnection) driver;
 if (mobileDriver.getNetworkConnection() != ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE) {
   // enabling Airplane mode
   mobileDriver.setNetworkConnection(ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE);
 }
```

But when I create AndroidDriver object and typecast it with above code, getting error that such typecast is not possible.

Any other way ?

Comment: We do it using a small custom app that appium runs, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This helper method will help you to turn on the wifi while your test case is still running:

```
static AppiumDriver driver;    

public static void wifiOff() throws InterruptedException {
    NetworkConnection mobileDriver = (NetworkConnection) driver;
    if (mobileDriver.getNetworkConnection() != ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE) {
       // enabling Airplane mode
       mobileDriver.setNetworkConnection(ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE);
    }
}
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hardware keys.
Write the steps to turn it on and off by using hardware buttons.

Comment: this will only work until the next OS update and change of menu structure

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Appium Java API docs](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/HasNetworkConnection.html) you'd do something like this (I haven't tested it):

```
driver.setConnection(Connection.AIRPLANE);
```

Note that only the Android driver supports this (not the iOS driver). See [Adjusting Network Connection](https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/writing-running-appium/network_connection/).

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can switch between ON/OFF options of Airplane mode only in Android. There is still no option to do that on iOS. This being said, this is what you would do to enable/disable airplane mode in Android.

```
((AndroidDriver) DRIVER).setConnection(Connection.AIRPLANE);
boolean connectionStatus = ((AndroidDriver) DRIVER)
    .getConnection()
    .equals(Connection.AIRPLANE);
if (connectionStatus) {
    //Then do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Appium Latest Java client you can do it using
**To disable Wifi and Data in Android:**
driver.setConnection(new ConnectionStateBuilder().withWiFiDisabled().withDataDisabled().build());

**To enabled WiFI and Data in Android:**
driver.setConnection(new ConnectionStateBuilder().withWiFiEnabled().withDataEnabled().build());

**To Enable and Disable Airplane mode in iOS you can refer below article:**
[Internet Offline Scenario Automation on Android and iOS Mobile App](https://dzone.com/articles/internet-offline-scenario-automation-on-android-and-iOS-mobile-App)