# Appium: How to resolve Class cast exception for iOS driver? "java.lang.ClassCastException"

Tags: automated-testing, appium, ios, seetest

I referred to one of the answers posted in this forum and when I attempted to run following code

```
    NetworkConnection mobileDriver = (NetworkConnection) appiumDriver;
   if (mobileDriver.getNetworkConnection() != ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE) {
      // enabling Airplane mode
      mobileDriver.setNetworkConnection(ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE);
    }
```

I get following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.mobile.NetworkConnection
```

Here is the link to the post which I had referred to [How can I switch ON/OFF AIRPLANE mode and wifi using Appium?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/how-can-i-switch-on-off-airplane-mode-and-wifi-using-appium)

Comment: Provide a link in your original post to the post in this forum from where you got this information.

Comment: @BillHileman I have provided the link in my post.

Comment: That was helpful, thanks.  I believe the last offered answer to your original post answers your question: it is currently not possible to do what you want in ios, only android.  You probably should have continued this in your original post instead of starting a new one.  As the original offerer of the solution you attempted why it doesn't work, I don't recognize the method.  Notice his example has the driver pre-defined as a static AppiumDriver before casting it, though.

Comment: static doesn't work
here is my code:

public static void turnWifiOff() throws InterruptedException {
    NetworkConnection mobileDriver = (NetworkConnection) appiumDriver;
    if (mobileDriver.getNetworkConnection() != ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE) {
      // enabling Airplane mode
      mobileDriver.setNetworkConnection(ConnectionType.AIRPLANE_MODE);
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't support NetworkConnection, so to turn off wifi, you can open the Control Center, you can do that with

```
public static void openControlCenter() throws InterruptedException

        {
            new TouchAction(DriverConfig.getInstance().getDriver()).press(point(250, 735)).waitAction(waitOptions(Duration.ofSeconds(3))).moveTo(point(250, -460)).release()
                    .perform();
            DriverConfig.getInstance().getDriver().findElement(By.name("wifi-button")).click();
            DriverConfig.getInstance().getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeWindow[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]")).click();
        }
```